# Using argparse in google colab. Not working with space in folder name "gdrive/My Drive/"

Tags: python, shell, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use google colab to train my CNN on a dataset that is located in my google drive.
I run the training by a shell command, like:

```
!python train.py --images_dataset=/content/gdrive/My Drive/...
```

However the name "/content/gdrive/My Drive/..." with the space in "My Drive" gives the argparse an error. Argparse receives everything after the space as an argument.

I get the following error: `train.py: error: unrecognized arguments: Drive/training_unet/training/val_images/validation Drive/training_unet/model/model`

How can i bypass this ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by placing " " around the folder name with a space in it.
So instead of '/content/gdrive/My Drive/...' ill use '/content/gdrive/"My Drive"/...' . :)